# My LG X Charge phone dropped in water, and I had some trouble after fishing it out! Help?

Tags: hardware, lg, water-damage

OK, so I accidentally dropped my LG X Charge (Android) smartphone in water, & I fished it out, but I had some trouble & fumbling & rigamarole to go through afterwards:

1. I had trouble getting the phone cover & case off, & I struggled for about a minute to remove them
2. The phone was turned on when it fell in the water, & after I fished it out, the home screen turned on like normal, & I could access what I had been doing for a few seconds, until the screen turned black with little gray stripes; this happened a couple of times, until the screen didn't turn on at all (but the phone still made noises & things like nothing had happened)
3. I then remembered that I should have kept the phone powered down as soon as it had been retrieved from the water, & I pressed the power button for a few seconds to turn it off
   3B. However, my phone buttons are very sensitive, & even when I just barely grazed the power button without meaning to touch it, the phone would power back up, & I'd have to turn it off again; this happened a few more times (but not all consecutively) until I finally managed to get it in a Ziploc bag full of rice (see below)
4. I gently shook the phone to get the water out, per the instructions that one website provided; I managed to get some of the water out, but not all of it, I fear
5. My smartphone is one of those that doesn't have a removable battery cover, so I was unable to remove that to get rid of any water that might be trapped underneath it
6. I know the LG G6 smartphone is waterproof, but I don't think the LG X Charge is...
7. I wasted valuable minutes calling my daddy on the phone, & telling him what happened
8. With the help of my grandma, I put the phone in a bowl full of rice...but I initially forgot to put it all in a Ziploc bag, & I had to go back & fix that!
9. Not only that, but at least one website I saw, said that your phone should be facing screen up at all times...& I realized too late that I occasionally had my phone facing *downwards* while I was tending to it post-retrieval!  Not to mention, it had been facing downward in the bowl of rice before I transferred it all into the Ziploc bag!

All in all, from the time I fished my phone out of the water at approximately 8:50 A.M., it took 17 minutes for me to go through nearly all of the above issues...with the phone & rice finally transferred from the bowl to the Ziploc bag no later than 9:40 A.M.

Tell me the truth, folks: What are the chances that my phone will make it out all right when I check on it at 9:30 A.M. on Monday morning? I'm really worried... :-(